# How to find out the default editor for man pages on osx?

Tags: macos, vim, case-sensitive, manpage

I want to make the default editor for man pages to be `vi`.  Right now it is something else.

I know it is something else, because when I try to do a case insensitive search, it doesn't work the way it does in vim:

```
/someWord\c
```

the above does not work in man pages, but it does work in vim.

How do I find out the editor for man pages?  thank

Comment: "editing" ≠ "viewing". "based on" ≠ "the same as". "vi" ≠ "vim".

Answer (score 3):

The default **pager** for `man` is `less`. When `-i` is passed to `less` searches with no capital letters are case-insensitive.

Comment: the `less` man page says "*Commands are based on both more and vi*", which made me think that the same things in vi should work here.

Comment: [Pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager). "based on", not "same as".

Answer (score 0):

The default pager for man is less.  To use vim as the pager, just place the following code in your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc.

```
export MANPAGER="/bin/sh -c \"col -b | vim -c 'set ft=man ts=8 nomod nolist nonu noma' -\""
```

The above command uses the col utility to remove extra ^H (backspace) characters. Next it pipe's the output to vim with the options below.

- ft=man enables the coloring of the man page.
- ts=8 ensures the width of tab characters matches less.
- nomod removes the modification warning when trying to quit.
- nonu removes line numbers.
- nolist disables listchars so trailing whitespace and extra tabs are
  not highlighted.
- noma prevents the buffer contents from being changed.